# Overhead of Composite Indexes

Tags: mysql, innodb, composite-index

I have many tables where I have indexes on foreign keys, and clustered indexes which include those foreign keys.  For example, I have a table like the following:

```
TABLE: Item
------------------------
id       PRIMARY KEY
owner    FOREIGN KEY
status

... many more columns
```

MySQL generates indexes for primary and foreign keys, but sometimes, I want to improve query performance so I'll create clustered or covering indexes.  This leads to have indexes with overlapping columns.

```
INDEXES ON: Item
------------------------
idx_owner (owner)
idx_owner_status (owner, status)
```

If I dropped `idx_owner`, future queries that would normally use `idx_owner` would just use `idx_owner_status` since it has `owner` as the first column in the index.

Is it worth keeping `idx_owner` around?  Is there an additional I/O overhead to use `idx_owner_status` even though MySQL only uses part of the index?

Edit: I am really only interested in the way **InnoDB** behaves regarding indexes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short Answer**
Drop the shorter index.

**Long Anwser**
Things to consider:

Drop it:

- Each `INDEX` is a separate BTree that resides on disk, so it takes space.
- Each `INDEX` is updated (sooner or later) when you `INSERT` a new row or an `UPDATE` modifies an indexed column.  This takes some CPU and I/O and buffer_pool space for the 'change buffer'.
- Any *functional* use (as opposed to performance) for the shorter index can be performed by the longer one.

Don't drop it:

- The longer index is bulkier than the shorter one.  So it is less cacheable.  So (in extreme situations) using the bulkier one in place of the shorter one *could* cause more I/O.  A case that aggravates this:  `INDEX(int, varchar255)`.

It is very rare that the last item really overrides the other items.

**Bonus**

A "covering" index is one that contains *all* the columns mentioned in a `SELECT`.  For example:

```
SELECT status FROM tbl WHERE owner = 123;
```

This will touch *only* the BTree for `INDEX(owner, status)`, thereby being noticeably faster than

```
SELECT status, foo FROM tbl WHERE owner = 123;
```

If you really need that query to be faster, then replace *both* of your indexes with `INDEX(owner, status, foo)`.

**PK in Secondary key**

One more tidbit...  In InnoDB, the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY` are implicitly appended to every secondary key.  So, the three examples are really

```
INDEX(owner, id)
INDEX(owner, status, id)
INDEX(owner, status, foo, id)
```

**More discussion** in my blogs on [*composite indexes*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index1) and [*index cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).